# OleDb Insert into Excel file skips "empty" rows

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I am strugegling with OleDb insert command into Excel file. It skips rows that were deleted in past.

In my C# code I have following insert call via OledDb command.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [input$] ([RowName], [RowValue]) VALUES ('blah', 'super blah')";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

after this insert table looks like this:

```
RowName | RowValue
blah    | super blah
        |
```

so far so good. Problems occurs when user deletes values from this table (press Delete key). When I call another insert into the same table I expected values to be inserted into first empty row (in this case it should be row 1), but it actually inserts values into second row.

Insert command:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [input$] ([RowName], [RowValue]) VALUES ('blah2', 'weak blah')";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

// Expected result:
RowName | RowValue
blah2   | weak blah
        | 

// Actual result
RowName | RowValue
        | 
blah2   | weak blah
```

Is there any way (without using ID row and use updates instead of inserts) how to fix this error?

Comment: Probably related to this well known behavior of Excel http://www.accountingweb.com/article/resetting-last-cell-excel-worksheet/221618

Comment: @Steve good point/article, but unfortunately it does not provides any information, how to fix this issue from C# code (only via VBA macro) and using oleDb.

Comment: Yes I know, this is the reason I have not posted an answer. Just to check if this is the problem, you could add the macro to your sheet, run it and then retest your app. If the problem goes away then this is the problem, but as far as I know, you need to use COM Interop to run the same kind of macro from your NET app. Not very complicated now that you can bundle the interop types directly in your app but this depends on your requirements. If the macro fixes the problem you could search this site for 'fixing excel used range'